# How do I override the grant_heading in the Google API request for permission page

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security

I'm running `Grails 2.3.6`.

My BuildConfig.groovy contains:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"
compile ":spring-security-oauth:2.0.1.1"
```

My `Config.groovy` contains:

```
oauth {
  providers {
    google {
        api = GoogleApi
        key = 'my-google-api-key.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        secret = 'secret_key'
        successUri = '/oauth/google/success'
        failureUri = '/oauth/google/failure'

        scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

        callback = "${grails.serverURL}/oauth/google/callback"
    }
  }
  debug = true
}
```

When the login process gets to the Google "Request for Permission" page the DIV with the ID "grant_heading" content displays:

```
my-google-api-key.apps.googleusercontent.com is requesting permission to:
...
```

How and/or where do I change "my-google-api-key.apps.googleusercontent.com" to something more informative to a naive user. I've looked in https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect and cannot seeing anything obvious that would allow me to control "grant_heading" contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to providing a friendly user acceptance screen is to use OAuth 2 as described here https://github.com/donbeave/grails-spring-security-oauth-google you will need to add some additional dependencies per http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth-google and http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core. I followed the described steps and ensured I had specified GoogleApi20. This provided the user acceptance screen I was after.